# asciidoc: how to include only title from a .adoc file?

Tags: asciidoc

I'm creating my curriculum vitae in asciidoc.

```
curriculum-vitae/
  - _includes/experiences.adoc
  - curriculum-vitae.adoc
  - resume.adoc
```

---

I'm trying to reuse the content of `_includes/experiences.adoc` to include only the title from it into resume.adoc

I used tags, but it's a lot verbose:

```
// tag::title[]
== Experience one
*Compagny name, Location* - Dates

// end::title[]
```

---

## It's there a simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

That is the simplest way to do it with just AsciiDoc markup. You'll have to get used to that level of verbosity since that's how tagged includes work.

Any other solution is more work, such as conditional content (similar verbosity, but requires attribute definitions, too) or an Asciidoctor extension that provides a macro (you have to write code).

Have you achieved your goal? You state that you want to "include only the title," but your tagged block also contains `*Compagny name, Location* - Dates`.

Let's assume that the `experiences.adoc` file should contain details for multiple companies. You can nest tags and use [tag filtering](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/directives/include-tagged-regions/#tag-filtering) to provide flexibility in what gets included.

If you change your `experiences.adoc` to contain:

```
// tag::company[]
== Experience one

// tag::body[]
*Company name, Location* - Dates
// end::body[]
// end::company[]

// tag::company2[]
== Experience two

// tag::body[]
*Company name2, Location2* - Dates
// end::body[]
// end::company2[]
```

You could include only the title for the first company in `resume.adoc` using this include:

```
include::_includes/experiences.adoc[tags=company;!body]
```

The `;` in the `tags` attribute separates one tag from another, and the `!body` says "don't include this tag."

You could include the full details in `curriculum-vitea.adoc` using this include:

```
include::_includes/experiences.adoc[tag=company]
```

Note: pay attention to using the `tag` or `tags` attribute, or you'll get errors during transformation.

That structure lets you define tags for every company you want to use in your resumé.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use an extension already created, so you do not "you have to write code" I can recommend

https://github.com/verhas/jamal

that I created to be a meta markup usable with Asciidoctor along with many other markups or markdowns (sic). This extension provides different possibilities, one is including other files, and the include macro has an option "lines" that can be used to specify the lines you want to include.

This will require that your title is on the given line, but that is usually the first one anyway. In that case, you can write

```
{@include [lines=1] _includes/experiences.adoc}
```

Even though I created Jamal and I am a proud father, I would not recommend using it ONLY for this very purpose, but you may bump into other limitations of Asciidoc or some other markup where Jamal may come to your rescue.

Also, I do not use the word 'limitations' as something not good. Markdown, Asciidoc, and other formats are there to describe the structure. Gathering, transforming, and inserting information from other information sources (files) is a cross-cutting concern that these formats handle only in a limited manner. On the other hand, Jamal was created for that very purpose, and extends the functionality of Asciidoc, Markdownand does not compete with it in the core functions of that.